# Power Mac G4 - AirPort card too big for slot

Tags: hardware, airport, power-mac

I have an old Power Mac G4, for which I acquired an AirPort card, and tried to follow these simple instructions from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYR8MaWl_dg) but it turns out that the card does not physically fit into the slot. It's too wide.

I've attached 3 photos to show the comparative width of the card and the slot, and the nature of the slot it needs to fit into. As you can see, it's quite different from the hardware shown in the video tutorial.

What I'd like to know, is what kind or model of AirPort card does this Mac take? I assumed it was the type shown in the photos, but that's obviously wrong.

[image: slot card hardware]

[image: slot card width]

[image: slot card width]

Comment: OK, so I've updated the question with a 3rd photo, to show more clearly the hardware difference.

Comment: Wasn't holding out and since Tetsujin had answered at the same time I commented I turned to other questions.  The search term I used was "AirPort card for Power Mac G4", without the quotes, and then reviewed several of the top hits.  One of which was http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Apple/M7600LLE/ as well as others that showed specs and compatibility.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's the exact card that I have in my hand, and which doesn't fit. What is the key difference I am looking for, before I buy another card which doesn't fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer, thanks to [this PDF document](http://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/powermac/pmg4_mir_fw800.pdf).

- On pages 68 - 70 it shows fitting the AirPort card I have, and it matches the YouTube tutorial I had linked in the question.
- On pages 71 - 73 it shows fitting an AirPort Extreme card.

In both cases, in the document, there are photographs which allow one to compare the two hardware configurations. It's not too difficult to compare the photos in the question to the photos in the document.

Based on those photos, I got myself an AirPort Extreme card, and it fits easily and works! (Photos attached)

[image: AirPort Extreme 1]

[image: AirPort Extreme 2]

[image: AirPort Extreme 3]

[image: AirPort Extreme 4]

Answer (score 2):

From [Power Mac G4 MDD AirPort Card Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Power+Mac+G4+MDD+AirPort+Card+Replacement/1617)
It depends which Power Mac G4 you have.

> The Power Mac G4 Uses the standard PCMCIA AirPort card found in Macs from 1999-2004.

[image]

> The Firewire 800 Model uses an AirPort Extreme Card found in iBook G4's And 1Ghz+ iMac G4's.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The fitting I'm looking at appears to suit neither of the two photos you posted. Is there a 3rd option?

Comment: it would help to know what model it is - otherwise we're all just guessing - http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/powermac_g4/index-powermac-g4.html

Comment: Its "Identifier" is PowerMac3,6 - which makes one of the last 7 in that list

Comment: then it's the first one - http://www.amazon.com/Original-Apple-Mac-Airport-802-11b-Wireless/dp/B000IBSEZO

Comment: I don't understand how that card is different from the card I have in my hands ...

Comment: it's smaller & has a different connector.  The one you have is clearly the other one - PC24H & 600-9236 visible on both my pic & yours

Comment: The picture of the Amazon item also shows  PC24H & 600-9236 ...

Comment: OK, so I've updated the question with a 3rd photo, to show more clearly the hardware difference.

Comment: http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Apple/M7600LLE/ shows 3 macs listed as 3,6 two it fits, the other it doesn't. The APNs are 630-2283 & 630/2283/C I have no clue of they're different sizes or different spec altogether. Your card is the /C variant